# Using WCF programming model for general application development as well?

Tags: frameworks, wcf

This may sound weird or funny but I need to ask this question for clarification. Basically I like the WCF programming model. So assuming I don't strictly have requirements for the 'service' based application, can I still go ahead and leverage the WCF infrastructure?

I know technically it is possible, however I want to know if there is noticeable penalty in doing so. I know I can improve performance by using appropriate binding (say, NetNamedPipesBinding).

So how can I take better care of performance and moreover, besides performance, what are other aspects I should be concerned about?

Comment: what *kind* of application? What for? Rendering a Form? No.  Rendering Html? Possibly (but still no). Network communication? Probably yes

Comment: In that case, you might also like Juval Lowy's [Every class a WCF service](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/ARCast+with+Ron+Jacobs/ARCastTV-Every-Class-a-WCF-Service-with-Juval-Lowy) screen cast!

Comment: We can for now eliminate presentation layer and consider the remaining like the application layer, domain layer and even the data access layer. While I am expecting an rhetoric 'no' I am keen to know 'why'. What is so wrong with WCF programming model for regular coding. As an afterthought, even a presentation later can use WCF RESTful services together with a UI layer (coded with ExtJs) that honors json data.

Comment: Marc, I saw this video more than 2 yrs back. Juval advocates the idea strongly, however the interviewer wasn't convinced. BTW, this link doesn't have the video.

Comment: Marc, here is a link where Juval talks about the idea in an another interview: http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=520    I am presently going through the transcript.

Answer (score 1):

We have actually tried this. I listened to a podcast that had the idea that every class should have a WCF interface.

On the plus side:

- It forces you think more about how parts of your system interact
- When we needed to spilt the application over 2 machines, it was just a config change

One the negative

- There was a lot of extra work on the configuration and time lost due to config errors
- What I think happens: Say you have a 1 MB object and you send it over WCF named pipes, although it is all in memory you still "send" 1 MB. If you just use classes you send a pointer.

On balance I would not try this again, although WCF 4 with less config would make it more doable.

Comment: Thanks Shiraz. This is a useful input. On the negatives you pointed out, 1) Within a tier, I may not take the configuration route, but may be a hard-coded route (a helper configuration class). This way I will minimize my configuration scope. 2) I will have to either figure out a way for reference or build a common context. Can you point out more negatives you struggled with?

Comment: Hi Shiraz ... can you throw some light on your experience from the performance standpoint? Did the WCF framework have a significant impact?